# How to handle this exceptions in flutter?

Tags: exception, flutter, dart

as I am new to the flutter, I came across the following exception while making a test app with the HTTP module and can't seem to find a solution around. Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
Future addProduct(Product product) {
    const url = 'wrong_url_that_throws_format_error';
    return http
        .post(
      url,
      body: json.encode({
        'title': product.title,
        'description': product.description,
        'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
        'price': product.price,
        'isFavorite': product.isFavorite,
      }),
    ).then((response) {
      // Do things if successful
    }).catchError((error) {
      throw error;
    });
}


// And in the widget
addProduct(_editedProduct).catchError((_) {
   // this return will throw exception saying:
   // Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Null>'
   return showDialog(
     context: context,
     builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
       title: const Text('Oops'),
       content: const Text('Something went wrong.'),
       actions: <Widget>[
         FlatButton(
           child: const Text('Ok'),
           onPressed: () {
             Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
           },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}).then((_) {
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
  });
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
});
```

Comment: The code is very verbose. Try to use async/await and surround the await in a try/catch as you would do with nomal sync code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, the returned type was `Future(dynamic)`, while the expected returning type was a `FutureOr(Null)`. As the message says, `FutureOr<Null>` isn't a subtype of `Future<dynamic>`.

You can fix that by specifying the returning type of `showDialog`, so it returns the right type. Instead of:

```js
return showDialog(...)
```

use:

```
return showDialog<Null>(...)
```